# Duplicated rows of Google cloud billing data

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I extracted GCP billing data through BigQuery. I made queries to retrieve data for particular time duration and then I found two types of duplicate data:

1. duplicate data resulted from unnesting the label column
2. duplicate data results from normal query (Like as below) rows with fully the same value for all columns.

````
      billing_account_id AS id,
      service.id AS ServiceId,
      service.description AS ServiceDescription,
      sku.id AS SkuId,
      sku.description AS SkuDescription,
      usage_start_time,
      usage_end_time,
      project.id AS ProjectId,
      project.number AS ProjectNumber,
      project.name AS ProjectName,
      project.labels as ProjectLabels,
      project.ancestry_numbers AS ProjectAncestryNumbers,
      labels   AS Labels,
      system_labels  AS SystemLabels,
      location.location AS Location,
      location.country AS Country,
      location.region AS Region,
      location.zone AS Zone,
      SUBSTRING(cast(export_time as string), 1, 19) AS ExportTime,
      cost AS Cost,
      currency AS Currency,
      currency_conversion_rate AS CurrencyConversionRate,
      usage.amount AS UsageAmount,
      usage.unit AS UsageUnit,
      usage.amount_in_pricing_units AS UsageAmountInPricingUnits,
      usage.pricing_unit AS UsagePricingUnit,
      credits  AS Credits,
      invoice.month AS InvoiceMonth,
      cost_type AS CostType,
      adjustment_info.id AS adjustmentInfoId,
      adjustment_info.description AS adjustmentInfoDescription,
      adjustment_info.mode AS adjustmentInfoMode,
      adjustment_info.type AS adjustmentInfoType
    FROM 
    'NAME OF TABLE' 
    WHERE DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) BETWEEN subtractFromTime(utcnow(),60,'Day','yyyy-MM-dd')AND formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyy-MM-dd')```


**I'd like to know why there are duplicate data? How they can be handled and how can be sure that cost calculation has not been affected by duplicate data?**

Appreciate it if anyone can help me.


Bests,
Shokoufeh
````

Answer (score 1):

**1. Why rows get duplicated when un-nesting the labels field?**

When you are un-nesting a repeated type field like `labels`, duplication of rows is expected. To be precise, each row gets duplicated based on the length of that row's `labels` array.

[image: Unnest count vs total labels]

**2. Why are there duplicate rows even before un-nesting?**

If you create 2 Compute Engine VMs of exact config and location, the idle usage rows in the billing export of those 2 VMs are exactly the same unless labelled. The export table doesn't have an explicitly exposed primary key.

The export table's granularity is only until service & SKUs and not per resource. This leads to duplicate looking data but they are actual valid usages.